# Insert multiple checkboxes into two columns in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

**UPDATE - I have updated my question and added my code. I know mysql* functions are deprecated in version 7 of PHP I am running version 5.5. I wish to continue using these functions. My code at present inserts my 14 checkboxes into a seperate column for each (exlcuding my userID which stores the logged on users ID). I want to be able to insert the name of my checkbox into my eNISATID column and the value of my checkbox (1 or 0) into my eNISAT_watch column, along with the users ID from the session.**

I am new to PHP. I am looking guidance on how to insert two values for each checkbox into my table in a seperate row. I have 14 checkboxes, which I wish to name 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc...(which will insert into eNISATID column). I want each name of the checkbox to insert into my 'eNISATID' column (1-14), as well as value of 1 or 0 into 'eNISAT_watch' depending if the checkbox has been selected or not.

My table has the following structure:

- `eNISATanswersID` (AUTO-INCREMENT)
- 'user_id' (Users id who is logged on)
- `eNISATID` (I want this to be the name of my checkbox, 1-14)
- `eNISAT_watch` (value or 1 or 0 depending if the checkbox has been selected or not)

Can anyone help on how best to approach this?

Thank you

```
<?php  
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{  
header("Location: eNISATVids.php");

    $userID=$_SESSION['user'];
    $cb_names = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14');
foreach ($cb_names as $cb) {
    $cb_val = isset($_POST['$cb']) ? 1 : 0;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO enisatanswer (user_id, eNISATID, eNISAT_watch) VALUES ('$userID', '$cb', $cb_val)";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
if($query==true)
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Your choices have inserted Successfully \n \n Please click on Display eNISAT Tutorials at the buttom of the page to view your videos ")</script>';  
   }  
else  
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
   }  
}  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
/<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<br>
<center>
<h2>Please select the tasks you require assistance with, before clicking DISPLAY ENISAT TUTORIALS:<h2>
<br>
<table align="center" height="0" width="70%" border="1" bgcolor = "white">
   <form  action="" method="post"

   <tr> 
      <td colspan="2">Tick each relevant box:</td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to login</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"></td>   
   <tr>  
      <td>How to manage your worktray</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="2" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your visual settings (Colours and text size)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="3" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your own password on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="4" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to logout of the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="5" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to search for a client on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="6" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr> 
      <td>How to start an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="7" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>
      <td>How to finalise an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="8" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to print an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="9" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to create a client and referral manually through Find on H+C</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="10" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from LCID (LCID Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="11" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from Soscare (Soscare Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="12" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to reassign a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="13" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to close a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="14" value="1"></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>  
      <td  <td><button name="submit" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='eNISATVids.php'">Display eNISAT Tutorials</button></td>
</tr> 
</table>  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**UPDATE - Can anyone help me with my second query. I have matched eNISATID (checkbox name from enisatanswer) to eNISATID (PRIMARY KEY from enisatquestion to uniquely identify the row for a video) as a foreign key.**

Here is my code to display my videos from my enisatquestion table based on the checkbox values inserted. I have tried two different queries as shown. One is commented out with //.

```
<?php  

    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) header("Location: index.php");

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array( $res );

    $userID=$_SESSION['user'];

    //$query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion INNER JOIN enisatanswer ON eNISATID = eNISATID WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user'] AND eNISAT_watch = 1";
    $query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion, enisatanswer.eNISATID = enisatquestion.eNISATID AND user_id = $userID";
    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    /* A default message if the query fails or there are no records */
    $enisatquestion='<h2>Sorry, there are no records</h2>';


    if( $result ) {/* if there is a recordset, proceed and generate html table */
        $enisatquestion = "<table >";
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td></tr>";
        }
        $enisatquestion .= "</table>";    
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="home.php?home">Return to Homepage</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<br>

    <center>
   <h2>Click on the each link to open your tutorial in Windows Media Player<h2>
   <br>
    <?php
        /* output the html table here, below your header */
        echo $enisatquestion;
        /*
            If the query failed then the default gets displayed
        */
    ?>  
</div> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: We're not here to write code for you from scratch, we'll help you fix your code. Please show what you tried.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for your reply. I have added my code, the reason I didnt in the first place, is that I thought it would complicate things, apologises my mistake. My code at present inserts the checkbox values into 14 seperate columns, as mentioned in my update. I need to insert the name of the checkbox into one column (eNISATID) and to insert the value of the checkbox into another  column (eNISAT_watch). Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array containing the names of all the checkboxes. Loop over the names, and test whether the corresponding checkbox was submitted or not (only checked boxes are submitted).

```
$cb_names = array('Log', 'Worktray', 'Visual', ...);
foreach ($cb_names as $cb) {
    $cb_val = isset($_POST[$cb]) ? 1 : 0;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (user_id, eNISATID, eNISAT_watch)
            VALUES ('$userID', '$cb', $cb_val)";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar. Thank you for your answer, much appreciated. I have updated my code to reflect your answer, although its not fully functioning. My userID inserts fine into each row, as does my eNISATID (I need this to be numbers 1-14) inserts 14 rows with numbers 1-14, but eNISAT_watch is inserting all zeros, not a 1 for the checkboxes selected. Can you help with this? Many Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake. `isset($_POST['$cb'])` should be `isset($_POST[$cb])` without the quotes.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thank you very much, your previous suggestion worked perfectly. I am on my final problem now. I have added the code for my second page where I wish to display only the video hrefs from my table based on the checkbox inserts from my previous page. Can you help with my final query? I have tried two seperate queries, the second one is not displaying any records, only displays my text - Sorry, there are no records.

Comment: If you have a new problem, post it as a new question, since you may need to accept a different answer for each question.

Comment: Ok @Barmar, I will do that thanks. I thought I would post it here so I could tag you (I dont think I am able to do that in a new question?), as you have been very helpful. I have posted several questions for various problems before and got no responses or negative comments about my code. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Post a link to the new question in a comment here.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165125/display-href-from-a-table-based-on-checkbox-values

Comment: Hi @Barmar. I solved my other problem myself. Thank you for offering to help with it, you are a gentleman and a scholar!