# Display href from a table based on checkbox values

Tags: php, mysql, video, checkbox

I am new to PHP. I am aware I am using mysql*functions, but I will continue to use them for this project. I am looking guidance on how to display videos based on checkbox values inserted into my database.  I have 14 checkboxes, which are named 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc...(which insert into eNISATID column). The name of each checkbox inserts into my 'eNISATID' (from enisatanswer) column (1-14), as well as value of 1 or 0 into 'eNISAT_watch' depending if the checkbox has been selected or not.

My first piece of code works fine and inserts into my database. Which is as follows:

```
<?php  
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{  
header("Location: eNISATVids.php");

    $userID=$_SESSION['user'];
    $cb_names = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14');
foreach ($cb_names as $cb) {
    $cb_val = isset($_POST['$cb']) ? 1 : 0;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO enisatanswer (user_id, eNISATID, eNISAT_watch) VALUES ('$userID', '$cb', $cb_val)";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
if($query==true)
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Your choices have inserted Successfully \n \n Please click on Display eNISAT Tutorials at the buttom of the page to view your videos ")</script>';  
   }  
else  
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
   }  
}  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
/<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<br>
<center>
<h2>Please select the tasks you require assistance with, before clicking DISPLAY ENISAT TUTORIALS:<h2>
<br>
<table align="center" height="0" width="70%" border="1" bgcolor = "white">
   <form  action="" method="post"

   <tr> 
      <td colspan="2">Tick each relevant box:</td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to login</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"></td>   
   <tr>  
      <td>How to manage your worktray</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="2" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your visual settings (Colours and text size)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="3" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your own password on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="4" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to logout of the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="5" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to search for a client on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="6" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr> 
      <td>How to start an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="7" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>
      <td>How to finalise an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="8" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to print an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="9" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to create a client and referral manually through Find on H+C</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="10" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from LCID (LCID Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="11" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from Soscare (Soscare Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="12" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to reassign a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="13" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to close a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="14" value="1"></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>  
      <td  <td><button name="submit" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='eNISATVids.php'">Display eNISAT Tutorials</button></td>
</tr> 
</table>  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**Can anyone help me with my second piece of code. I have matched eNISATID (checkbox name from enisatanswer) to eNISATID (PRIMARY KEY from enisatquestion to uniquely identify the row for a video) as a foreign key.**

My table for my checkbox responses has the following structure:

- `eNISATanswersID` (AUTO-INCREMENT)
- 'user_id' (Users id who is logged on)
- `eNISATID` (I want this to be the name of my checkbox, 1-14)
- `eNISAT_watch` (value of 1 or 0 depending if the checkbox has been selected or not)

My table for videos table has the following stucture:

-'eNISATID' (Primary Key - values 1-14)
-'eNISATQuestion' (Text that forms the wording on my href)
-'eNISATVideo' (URL for my video stored on my server)

** When I use a simple query to display all of the videos from my table, they display fine, but I wish to only dispay the videos relating to the checkbox selected and depending on the user_id of the logged on user. I feel that my SELECT query is the issue, can anyone advise.

Here is my code to display my videos from my enisatquestion table based on the checkbox values inserted. I have tried two different queries as shown. One is commented out with //. **

```
<?php  

    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) header("Location: index.php");

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array( $res );

    $userID=$_SESSION['user'];



  $query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion INNER JOIN enisatanswer WHERE enisatanswer.eNISATID = enisatquestion.eNISATID AND user_id = $userID AND eNISAT_watch = 1";

    /* A default message if the query fails or there are no records */
    $enisatquestion='<h2>Sorry, there are no records</h2>';


    if( $result ) {/* if there is a recordset, proceed and generate html table */
        $enisatquestion = "<table >";
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td></tr>";
        }
        $enisatquestion .= "</table>";    
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="home.php?home">Return to Homepage</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<br>

    <center>
   <h2>Click on the each link to open your tutorial in Windows Media Player<h2>
   <br>
    <?php
        /* output the html table here, below your header */
        echo $enisatquestion;
        /*
            If the query failed then the default gets displayed
        */
    ?>  
</div> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @wogsland. That helps

Comment: If you are aware of a mistake why are you still repeating it..Adapting it before it turns into a habit makes more sense.. By the time pass changing your habits is not that easy ;)

Comment: Hi @ern. Sorry I dont know what you mean.  Which mistake are you referring to? If it is my query, then I have a lack of knowledge to implement it, hence why I am posting a question for help. If you mean using mysql*functions I only have one week left to finish my project, this was the langauge I was taught. In future I will use mysqli or PDO if I intend any further projects. Can I ask, why the likes of yourself and wogsland refrain from offering any help in the form of answers but instead only criticise in the comments?

Comment: I mean mysql*functions .." why the likes of yourself and wogsland refrain from offering any help in the form of answers but instead only criticise in the comments?" .. As personal preference i will not give an answer a question which uses mysql*functions .. But I can't answer your question  in the name of wogsland .. Adapting into mysqli or PDO believe me it's easy before it's too late..

Comment: @ern thanks for being honest, and fair enough if that is your preference. If I had the knowledge and skill that the majority of members on here have, I would be willing to help people out with answers (after all that is what the site is for) especially knowing the stress that it has caused me personally trying to learn how to code within a deadline of 8 weeks for my studies

Answer (score 0):

It would be really useful if you post what happens when you run your code with the first SQL query (The second appears invalid, and is missing any JOIN clause).

To ensure nothing in your code is at fault, always run your SQL queries *directly* against the database itself first, ("hard-coding" any dynamic, form-based data to simulate an actual, user-generated query).

If you're on OS/X or Linux then using the mysql client to run your query will soon tell you if the query itself is at fault. Otherwise use phpMyAdmin (or whatever other GUI-based tool you wish) to achieve the same thing.

Once the database returns the data you expect, modify your PHP code to generate the correct SQL query, and work from there.

Comment: Hi @theruss thanks for your reply. On my first query I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\Tna\eNISATVids.php on line 14

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, the error I was getting was from the SESSION variable in my query. I used my initial query and updated as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion INNER JOIN enisatanswer WHERE enisatanswer.eNISATID = enisatquestion.eNISATID AND user_id = $userID AND eNISAT_watch = 1";
```